# How can we change the field name when authenticating with JWT

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $id = $this->getPayload()->get('sub');
    if (! $this->auth->byId($id)) 
    {
         return false;
    }
    return $this->user();
}

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
              echo "Invalid request!";
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            echo "Could not create a token!";
        }

        \Cookie::queue('token', $token, 3600);


    }
```

When printing `$id` it return to the id of user's table let say i don't have id I used `user_id` how can i change this and where please guide. Thanks

Comment: cant understand what you want to do can you describe more aboute your goals

Answer (score 0):

**byId**

`byId()` will search for primary key so make `user_id` primary key and make sure it is set for auto increment.

Comment: @Jacob I mean just make `user_id` column in your database table as primary key and auto increment. It will do the trick

Comment: Yes just did so didn't work, Even not able to login as well

Comment: Updated question